# Gráfico highcharts não aparece

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando usar o gráfico:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/

Porem salvo o arquivo da mesma forma e esse gráfico não aparece, ele é o unico que não funciona.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, pode tentar postar o que você tentou fazer?

Comment: apenas copiei e colei o html e js do jsfidle, o grafico não aparece.

Comment: Verifique se esta acessando usando localhost, pois chamadas ajax não são executadas com protocolo file:\\\

Comment: Deve ser isso, ta chamando file, como faço pra colocar localhost?

Comment: precisa de um servidor?

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá? estás a juntar o jQuery?

Comment: Não da erro, sim ja tem o jquery.Coloquei no servidor e tambem não roda o gráfico.

Comment: importei a jquery a parte,Erro: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Tens exatamente o mesmo HTML que o jsFiddle?

Comment: @WarLock você referenciou o Jquery antes dos outros scripts?

Comment: Mesmo codigo, todos os outros graficos funcionam.

Comment: Aqui o mesmo exemplo copiado e colado, e não aparece. http://jsfiddle.net/v7wq2bv2/2/

Comment: @WarLock Coloquei uma resposta, só faltava mesmo a Referência do Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhe se pode te ajudar o código abaixo.

Só acrescentei a Referência do Jquery.

```js
$(function () {

    Highcharts.data({
        csv: document.getElementById('tsv').innerHTML,
        itemDelimiter: '\t',
        parsed: function (columns) {

            var brands = {},
                brandsData = [],
                versions = {},
                drilldownSeries = [];

            // Parse percentage strings
            columns[1] = $.map(columns[1], function (value) {
                if (value.indexOf('%') === value.length - 1) {
                    value = parseFloat(value);
                }
                return value;
            });

            $.each(columns[0], function (i, name) {
                var brand,
                    version;

                if (i > 0) {

                    // Remove special edition notes
                    name = name.split(' -')[0];

                    // Split into brand and version
                    version = name.match(/([0-9]+[\.0-9x]*)/);
                    if (version) {
                        version = version[0];
                    }
                    brand = name.replace(version, '');

                    // Create the main data
                    if (!brands[brand]) {
                        brands[brand] = columns[1][i];
                    } else {
                        brands[brand] += columns[1][i];
                    }

                    // Create the version data
                    if (version !== null) {
                        if (!versions[brand]) {
                            versions[brand] = [];
                        }
                        versions[brand].push(['v' + version, columns[1][i]]);
                    }
                }

            });

            $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
                brandsData.push({
                    name: name,
                    y: y,
                    drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
                });
            });
            $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
                drilldownSeries.push({
                    name: key,
                    id: key,
                    data: value
                });
            });

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares. November, 2013'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total percent market share'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Brands',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: brandsData
                }],
                drilldown: {
                    series: drilldownSeries
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<!-- Data from www.netmarketshare.com. Select Browsers => Desktop share by version. Download as tsv. -->
<pre id="tsv" style="display:none">Browser Version Total Market Share
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 26.61%
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0 16.96%
Chrome 18.0 8.01%
Chrome 19.0 7.73%
Firefox 12 6.72%
Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0 6.40%
Firefox 11 4.72%
Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0 3.55%
Safari 5.1 3.53%
Firefox 13 2.16%
Firefox 3.6 1.87%
Opera 11.x 1.30%
Chrome 17.0 1.13%
Firefox 10 0.90%
Safari 5.0 0.85%
Firefox 9.0 0.65%
Firefox 8.0 0.55%
Firefox 4.0 0.50%
Chrome 16.0 0.45%
Firefox 3.0 0.36%
Firefox 3.5 0.36%
Firefox 6.0 0.32%
Firefox 5.0 0.31%
Firefox 7.0 0.29%
Proprietary or Undetectable 0.29%
Chrome 18.0 - Maxthon Edition 0.26%
Chrome 14.0 0.25%
Chrome 20.0 0.24%
Chrome 15.0 0.18%
Chrome 12.0 0.16%
Opera 12.x 0.15%
Safari 4.0 0.14%
Chrome 13.0 0.13%
Safari 4.1 0.12%
Chrome 11.0 0.10%
Firefox 14 0.10%
Firefox 2.0 0.09%
Chrome 10.0 0.09%
Opera 10.x 0.09%
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 - Tencent Traveler Edition 0.09%</pre>
```

Comment: pode postar o html da forma de copiar e colar? porque aqui ainda nao aparece  nada.

Comment: Ainda não aparece nada.ja tentei baixando todos os js e chamando,inclusive copiei o codigo fonte desse frame seu exibido, e ainda não aparece nada, todos os .js foram chamados.

Comment: adicionei..........